# Windows command line, autocompleting paths

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

In a PowerShell console I use tab key for autocompleting paths. Is there some possibility to make shell append '\' char to the autocompleted path? (Like in linux, autocompleting goes with '/' there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) adds the "\" when tab-completing a path.

If you are coming from Linux, then you will probably like PSReadLine as it makes the command line more Linux-like.

Comment: Thanks for reply, PSReadLine is a very useful module. I have searched some registry tweak, but it seems to be no another way to add trailing slash. So, PSReadline is probably the best method to resolve this problem, thanks again.